# Extract multiple ranges from a numeric vector

Tags: r

First, I simplify my question. I want to extract certain ranges from a numeric vector. For example, extracting 3 ranges from `1:20` at the same time :

- 1 < x < 5
- 8 < x < 12
- 17 < x < 20

Therefore, the expected output is `2, 3, 4, 9, 10, 11, 18, 19`.

I try to use the function `findInterval()` and control arguments `rightmost.closed` and `left.open` to do that, but any arguments sets cannot achieve the goal.

```
x <- 1:20
v <- c(1, 5, 8, 12, 17, 20)

x[findInterval(x, v) %% 2 == 1]
# [1]  1  2  3  4  8  9 10 11 17 18 19

x[findInterval(x, v, rightmost.closed = T) %% 2 == 1]
# [1]  1  2  3  4  8  9 10 11 17 18 19 20

x[findInterval(x, v, left.open = T) %% 2 == 1]
# [1]  2  3  4  5  9 10 11 12 18 19 20
```

By the way, the conditions can also be a matrix like that :

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    5
[2,]    8   12
[3,]   17   20
```

I don't want to use `for` loop if it's not necessary.

I am grateful for any helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right path, and `left.open` indeed helps, but `rightmost.closed` actually concerns only the last interval rather than the right "side" of each interval. Hence, we need to use `left.open` twice. As you yourself figured out, it looks like an optimal way to do that is

```
x[findInterval(x, v) %% 2 == 1 & findInterval(x, v, left.open = TRUE) %% 2 == 1]
# [1]  2  3  4  9 10 11 18 19
```

Clearly there are alternatives. E.g.,

```
fun <- function(x, v)
  if(length(v) > 1) v[1] < x & x < v[2] | fun(x, v[-1:-2]) else FALSE
x[fun(x, v)]
# [1]  2  3  4  9 10 11 18 19
```

Comment: So excellent is your recursive function. Thank you very much!

Comment: I revise your code : `x[findInterval(x, v) %% 2 == 1 &
  findInterval(x, v, left.open = T) %% 2 == 1]` and get the same output. How about it ?

Answer (score 5):

I'd probably do it using purrr::map2 or Map, passing your lower-bounds and upper-bounds as arguments and filtering your dataset with a custom function

```
library(purrr)
x <- 1:20
lower_bounds <- c(1, 8, 17)
upper_bounds <- c(5, 12, 20)
map2(
    lower_bounds, upper_bounds, function(lower, upper) {
        x[x > lower & x < upper]
    }
)
```

Answer (score 4):

You may use  `data.table::inrange` and its `incbounds` argument. Assuming ranges are in a matrix 'm', as shown in your question:

```
x[data.table::inrange(x, m[ , 1], m[ , 2], incbounds = FALSE)]
# [1]  2  3  4  9 10 11 18 19
```

---

```
 m <- matrix(v, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an easy way just with `sapply()` :

```
x <- 1:20
v <- c(1, 5, 8, 12, 17, 20)
(v.df <- as.data.frame(matrix(v, 3, 2, byrow = T)))

  #   V1 V2
  # 1  1  5
  # 2  8 12
  # 3 17 20

y <- sapply(x, function(x){
  ind <- (x > v.df$V1 & x < v.df$V2)
  if(any(ind)) x else NA
})

y[!is.na(y)]
# [1]  2  3  4  9 10 11 18 19
```